# Return a string that has been created in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, return

The objective was to create a String toUppercase method if it did not exist. I got most of the code, but how do you return a string that has been created in a for loop?

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i > str.length; i++){
        char a = str.charAt(i);
        char b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        String t = Character.toString(b);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: *The objective was to create a String toUppercase method if it did not exist.* -- If what did not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `t` outside of the loop and assign with `+=` inside the loop.

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
    {
        String t = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char a = str.charAt(i);
            char b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
            t += Character.toString(b);
        }
        return t;
    }
```

That's what you'd do in case such a method didn't exist. Also next step would have been to take care of performance and heap impact may be using `StringBuilder`. But all these basic operations are already available in `java.lang.String` why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an empty string outside the loop and then append the character to it with `+=`

Example:

```
public String toUpperCase (String str) {
  String res = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char a = str.charAt(i);
    char b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
    res += Character.toString(b);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to write this function ?

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
{
    String t = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char a = str.charAt(i);
        char b = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        t = t + Character.toString(b);
    }

    return t;
}
```

A simple :

```
str.toUpperCase()
```

isn't enough ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your *accumulator* (`t`) outside the loop and initialize it with an empty value. However, I would start by making the method `static` (since it doesn't use any instance data). Next, I would prefer a `StringBuilder` as my accumulator. And I would use `String.toCharArray()` so I could use an enhanced for-each loop. Like,

```
public static String toUpperCase(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you're showing this way for efficiency, it is worth mentioning that you can do it more efficiently just by operating directly on the `char[]` from `toCharArray()`, then building a new string at the end. (At the very least, pre-size the string builder).